# In javascript, how can i know if an html object property is a property, a method or an event?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Here is an interesting issue I am trying to resolve in Javascript... Lets assume we have a HTML Object like an Anchor Tag, I can enumerate the properties of it but what I really need to do is to get the property along with the type of property it is: is it a property, a method or an event? How to get this type information?

Using jQuery I can check if it's a function `$.isFunction(reference)` but I am looking for a pure JS solution.

From what I understood a property is an object, an event is an object as well, so I just need to check if it has certain property to identify if it's an event or not.

The question is what is that property?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `typeof` identifies functions - also a property can't be an event ... though event handlers can be added using on*eventname* - so if the property starts with `on` it's likely an event handler - but on*eventname* will either be `null` or `function`

Comment: "From what I understood a property is an object" — No, properties are attached to objects, they can have any kind of value.

Comment: This is smelling rather like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it a property

Always

> a method

```
typeof thatPropertyValue === "function"
```

> an event

Almost never, but:

```
thatPropertyValue instanceof Event
```